# Set up local development environment for heroku facebook app

Tags: facebook, heroku, local, environment

I have my app up in canvas but am at somewhat of a loss as to how I can test locally. I'm building my app on top of nodeJs to give it a try. I have a dev app that hasn't been deployed to heroku so I'm all set there, save some details to follow. I know my computers IP address but I'm not sure if that's the one I need. How do I find the correct IP. Something like: 0.0.0.124:5000 is the example that's given. To summarize what I need to know:

A) how to find the correct local IP
B) how and where to configure apache server (I have the code from heroku just need to know what file it goes into and where to find it).
C) How to export port 80
D) find out if I need access to my local dsl router admin area to set static ip or use dynamic one

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the Heroku documentation:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#1-creating-a-development-facebook-app

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the IP address for a callback URL? If so, I recommend signing up with a dynamic DNS service so your home Internet connection has a consistent domain name even if your home IP address changes.

You'll also need to forward the appropriate port from your home router to your development machine.